# Применение фрагментного шейдера к текстуре

Tags: opengl, webgl

Допустим, у меня есть картинка, нарисованная в текстуру (или рендербуфер). Как мне применить к ней (целиком) некоторый фрагментный шейдер? Например, я хочу сделать все цвета бледнее (или ярче, или зеленее, не важно). Нужен ли какой-то вершинный шейдер, нужна ли какая-то команда draw?

Comment: Вам следует написать в вопросе, что вы пытаетесь нарисовать полупрозрачные предметы. А вообще, вот хороший урок на эту тему - https://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-OpenGL/Blending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл
https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/ru/webgl-image-processing.html
Там весь курс очень хороший.